# What do the numbers mean in awstats report?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, awstats

Under the "Links from an Internet Search Engine" in "Connect to site from" section, there are lines like

```
Google .com 0   / 24
```

What does the number 0 and 24 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are just a "quick view" of the **PAGES** and **HITS** you get for each entry.

[image]

If you click **"Full List"** you can see the headers which give the actual breakdown of numbers and the column headers showing what they represent.

[image]